# Set cookie to multiple domains

Tags: authentication, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-state

We have requirement that user session established in one region to be used in another region. Here one region is replication of other and we use cookies to track sessions

Our sample url: `app1.<replicated_region>.domain.com or app1.region.domain.com`.

If user session created in app1.<replicated_region>.domain.com, then we set cookie domain as app1.<replicated_region>.domain.com. But based on cookie principle, browser wont send this cookie, when they access app1.region.domain.com. When user accessing replicated region, the other region may be down.

I know we can't set wildcard character to domain and don't want to set same content cookie to multiple region domains.

Is there a way to achieve this?

thanks.